# When I Update my Phone to Android 12, Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, manifest

I was working on my project perfectly since I Update my phone to Android 12 unfortunately when I run the project to my phone this Error appears:

> Installation did not succeed.
> The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

> List of apks:
> [0] 'C:\Users\Microsoft\AndroidStudioProjects\YmmyServer\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
> Installation failed due to: 'null'
> Retry

This is My build.gradle(Project) File:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is My build.gradle(Module) File:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ymmyserver"
        minSdkVersion 30
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'
//    implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.1.0')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

And this is the Mainifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ymmyserver">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Ymmy">
        <activity android:name=".FoodList"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Ymmy.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SignIn" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What Should I do Please Help Me

Comment: try adding   android:exported="true">  to your MainActivity

Comment: Solved thanks it was very simple you are the Boss @Manjeetdeswal

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to use this tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for the activity

```
<activity 
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:exported="true">
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this is needed? I'm terrified by the idea that I need to add some random string I have no understanding of to my production code for it to start functioning.

Comment: it basically means whether or not the activity can be launched by components of other applications

Comment: in my case a service is started while first appeared the app. i just add android:exported="true" in the service as well as launcher activity in the manifest. it is okay now. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Solved by Adding android:exported="true" on the main Activity in Mainifest File:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
```